# How can i expand accordion when searching

Tags: javascript

I have two javascript codes. One for opening accordion and other for searching.
 I want to open the accordions when the search word match with the  tag's text.

```js
document.getElementById("defaultOpen").click();
var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
    acc[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
        this.classList.toggle("active");

        var panel = this.nextElementSibling;
        if (panel.style.display === "block") {
            panel.style.display = "none";
        } else {
            panel.style.display = "block";
        }
    });
}


(function(document) {
 'use strict';

 var LightTableFilter = (function(Arr) {

  var _input;
  // Get the element with id="defaultOpen" and click on it

  function _onInputEvent(e) {
   _input = e.target;
   var tables = document.getElementsByClassName(_input.getAttribute('data-table'));
   Arr.forEach.call(tables, function(table) {
    Arr.forEach.call(table.tBodies, function(tbody) {
     Arr.forEach.call(tbody.rows, _filter);
    });
   });
  }

  function _filter(row) {
   var text = row.textContent.toLowerCase(), val = _input.value.toLowerCase();
   row.style.display = text.indexOf(val) === -1 ? 'none' : 'table-row';
  }

  return {
   init: function() {
    var inputs = document.getElementsByClassName('light-table-filter');
    Arr.forEach.call(inputs, function(input) {
     input.oninput = _onInputEvent;
    });
   }
  };
 })(Array.prototype);

 document.addEventListener('readystatechange', function() {
  if (document.readyState === 'complete') {
   LightTableFilter.init();
  }
 });

})(document);
```

What should I do for this action?I tried so much to slove it even by using other codes but ...